# COVID-19 Human to Human 'Proximity' Logger

Tags: wireless, low-power, proximity-sensor

In the midst of the Corona Pandemic we are looking to develop a wearable sensor that when within approximately 2m of another (of the same type) of wearable sensor will log an event.

The ideal would be a low cost and very low power. It must work without line of sight since the sensor can be in your pocket etc. I've looked at all sorts of proximity sensors and none seem to be able to do the job.

My only solution I could come up with is a sub Ghz RF transceiver that polls (twice every second) and is in receive mode for the rest of the time and when a message is received an ACK is sent. The output power will be set very low (0 dbm) without an antenna so should get around 1.5 to 2.5 m range irrespective of a human body that is in between sender and receiver (If I go with my intuition).

Problem is that lowest RX current is around 7mA which means on a 1000mA battery will last less than a week.

Has any body done anything similar or have any advise on maybe another type of technology I can use?

Location is not important and it is most likely going to be indoor.

Any advise will be highly appreciated

Comment: *The output power will be set very low (0 dbm) without an antenna* 1) low/high is **relative**, in some circumstances 0 dBm is quite high. 2) you cannot "not have an antenna", you have 0 dBm of power and without an antenna it is not radiated. In the real world a small past of the power will be transmitted by the IC itself (for example by its internal bondwires) and whatever is connected to it (only a soldering pad? Then that will also be an antenna). The rest of the power will simply reflect back into the transmitter.

Comment: *...so should get around 1.5 to 2.5 m range irrespective of a human body that is in between sender and receiver* In some circumstances the range will be 10 cm and in other circumstances it will be 10 m or more. Can you live with that? Distance "measuring" on basis of signal strength is always extremely inaccurate. What if the signal reflects on some surface?

Comment: I don't have the link at hand but look up PPCTP - Apple and Google jointly created a new protocol which works on top of BLE, intended to be used in smartphones.

Comment: And, when the next virus comes along that the doctors recommend 4 metres distancing, you'll be sunk with your product.

Comment: @JanDorniak I've seen similar BLE proposals like that being mentioned before. Note how that relates to "proximity" in the sense of "nearby enough to be able to receive an advertisement and lure into shop". PPCTP doesn't do any actual measuring of the distance. It's more a in range/out of range decision. But please, anyone may prove me wrong and show an example how BLE or any RF signal strength solutions do (somewhat) accurate distance measuring. I'm not talking about time-delay based systems as those are accurate but complex.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have only read a summary on its privacy. But one of the newer BLE revisions has ToF measurement so it presumably wouldn't be hard to add this in a future revision to PPCTP - to store distance as well.

Comment: Cross posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61252121/4961700

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493011/covid-proximity-sensor-2-meters-range. Read the comments on it.

Comment: The whole concept is flawed. The real problem isn't proximity, it's infected people not being isolated. They can cough or sneeze further than 2m, leave the virus on surfaces etc. that infect others long after they have left. Just being in the same room may be enough. The only real solution is total lockdown, and thorough tracking and isolation of all contacts (not just those who strayed closer than 2m).

Comment: The proposed project won't be able to tell the difference between two people in the same room or separated by a wall, partition, window, etc. The "signal strength indicator" is generally a measure of the *quality* of the signal (throughput / errors, etc.) rather than just the signal strength.

Comment: Considering how many researchers have tried and failed to do this kind of thing (as soon as you add real-world issues like reflections, variable antenna patterns because of different ways of people holding the device, etc) I imagine this is just not really feasable.

Comment: I came accross this article: https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/health/coronavirus/121083996/coronavirus-new-zealand-considering-100m-contact-tracing-covidcard

A company in NZ developed a similar device using BLE. It is the size of a credit card and can last 12 months on a battery. How could one implement p2p BLE with such a low power consumption? Am I missing something?

Also the 2m range isn't important it is just to get an indication if two devices were close to each other (contact tracing). So ideally anything closer than 3m is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I once designed a non contact telephone line tracer. The specification was to be able to detect a 1Vpp 1kHz sinusoid signal on a 1 metre length of wire at a distance of 1 metre. The input was a probe tip connected to a static protected FET opamp with a high Q filter. I imagine a 2 metre range could be achieved by pushing the voltage up to about 9V.

The method I used was essentially an electrostatic pickup. A homemade near field RFID type thing might work as well. Hi Q Coil being fed at (say) 100kHz, with a simply LC being used as pickup. Similar to resonant power transfer.

Comment: If I see this correctly then this is a much more "controlled" situation. If the wire is OK you can follow the line at 1 m distance. If the line is broken you'd find there's a difference. OP's situation is much less controlled unless users wear a cap with the device up on a stick and only use it outdoors in open space (so there are almost no signal reflections).

Comment: Ooooh, that's worth a drawing, I think!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Just increase the frequency and shorten the "antenna". Its worth doing some experiments. The method I used was essentially an electrostatic pickup. A homemade near field RFID type thing might work as well. Hi Q Coil being fed at (say) 100kHz, with a simply LC being used as pickup. Similar to resonant power transfer.